# Getting "final" prepared statement from MySqlCommand

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prepared-statement

I have the following MySqlCommand:

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
cmd.CommandText = "REPLACE INTO `customer` VALUES( ?customerID, ?firstName, ?lastName)"

With cmd.Parameters
 .AddWithValue("?customerID", m_CustomerID)
 .AddWithValue("?firstName", m_FirstName)
 .AddWithValue("?lastName", m_LastName)
End With
```

I have a class that handles execution of MySqlCommands and I'd like to have it log every query to a file. I can retrieve the query/command being executed with:

```
cmd.CommandText
```

but that just returns the original **CommandText** with the parameters (?customerID, ?firstName, etc.) and not the actual substituted values added by the **AddWithValue** functions. How can I find out the actual "final" query that was executed?

Comment: Why do you need to know the "final" prepared statement?

Comment: I'm also needing to do this... ever get an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to build it yourself.

Parameters are not just plopped into a string and then run as a SQL statement. The RDBMS will actually prepare the SQL and then use the parameter values as needed. Therefore, there's not a single SQL statement going to the server. To see what the SQL would be, you would have to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("REPLACE INTO `customer` VALUES('" & m_CustomerID & _
    "', '" & m_FirstName & "', '" & m_LastName & "')")
```

Comment: The only difference is that this doesn't escape your param values... so that if m_FirstName has a single tick (') in it, this approach will produce a corrupt command string. Using MySqlParameters, Connector/NET will correctly escape the value. So it's not equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following:

```
dim tmpstring as string = MySqlCommand.CommandText
For each p as MySqlParameter in MySqlCommand.parameters
    tmpstring = tmpstring.replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
Next
```

This seems to output everything you need

Answer (score 1):

I havn't seen a method for this.

And in any case, prepared statements are sent to the server with the ?customerID,?firstname parameters, and then the actual parameters are sent seperately - the mysql driver doesn't build up a final sql query like you'd do if you didn't use prepared statements.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The reason I'm using prepared statements is to prevent SQL injection. Do you know if the .NET MySQL connector provides proper escape functions or something similar to help me build an injection-safe query prior to executing it?

Answer (score 1):

The parameterised method you're using should be okay for preventing SQL injection.

```
.AddWithValue("?customerID", m_CustomerID)
```

If m_CustomerID contains the text

```
Haha I'm stealing your data; drop table whatever;
```

Then it won't end up being executed on the server as such.  The `AddWithValue` sorts that out for you.

As for the actual executed query, you should be able to get that from the query-log, if it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need.

From what I've read, the query text isn't combined with the param values in the client - they are sent to the server for that.

To inspect what query was actually being sent to the server, I used mysqld logging. For my version of MySQL, I added this entry to the my.cnf:

```
log=queries.txt
```

Then, I was able to see clearly the effect of combining command text with parameters: in my case, after restarting the mysqld, I ran my unit tests and then opened the queries.txt file.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage logging yourself from the .NET application, your best bet is to continue using the MySqlCommand class with parameters to avoid SQL injection; however, when you log the CommandText, loop through the Parameters collection and log each one by name/type/value.